# How to filter data using Linq in List<object>

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am calling stored procedure to get data from database using Linq. This stored procedure is using more than one table to return result using join :

```
public static List<classname> GetMediaTemp()
{
var medialist = (from m in Context.sp_Temp() select new classname
                                            {
                                               str_image = m.str_image,
                                                str_image_type = m.str_image_type,
                                                str_photodrawvideo = m.str_photodrawvideo,
                                            }).ToList();
if (medialist.Count > 0)
{
   return medialist
}
}
```

Everything working fine but now i have to filter data in this object list like on the calling end

```
List<classname> photoList = GetMediaTemp();//Here i want to filter list on the basis on str_photodrawvideo column.
```

**Problem :**

How i can perform this filter ?

Thanks in Advance. For more info please let me know.

Comment: Why do you use a `List<object>` and not a `List<TypeOfMedialist>`? If you absolutely cannot have a strongly typed list (for example, you need to put lots of different types of objects into one list), maybe `objList.OfType<TypeOfMedialist>()` will help.

Answer (score 3):

you can do as below

```
var objList = Context.sp_Temp().ToList();
var photoList = objList.Where(o=>o._int_previous == 1).ToList();
```

Or

you can cast the `object` to Class which build the object list as below

```
var photoList = 
   (from pht in objList 
     let x=>(sp_TempResult)pht
     where x._int_previous == 1 select pht).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the type return by the `sp_Temp`? why you need object list?

Comment: i am getting {sp_TempResult} type.

Comment: @Sunny use `var objList = Context.sp_Temp().ToList();`

Comment: Yes. This is right way to achieve filters and also specify the return **"sp_TempResult"** type as the **"List<sp_TempResult>"** instead using object type.

Comment: @Damith in my question i am using the same.

Comment: @Sunny but you adding to `List<object>`, isn't it?

Comment: i am using class name as :
var list = (from m in sp_temp() select new classname{ name= m.name,type=m.type }).ToList(); as per your answer.
now i want to filter list on the basis of type

Comment: @Damith one more thing i am using the above code in method with return type List<classname>